# Running Metasploit on Ubuntu Error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/
Here is the site I used for the installation process
I typed

> msfconsole

after install rbenv ruby (I know its a longer installation, but I still did), and got this error.

> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in
>
> parse: (/opt/metasploit-framework/config/database.yml): mapping
>   values are not allowed in this context at line 9 column 22
>
> (Psych::SyntaxError)
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in
>   parse_stream
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in
>   parse
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in load
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:464:in block
>   in load_file
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:464:in open
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:464:in
>   load_file
>           from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/ui/console/driver.rb:164:in
>   initialize
>           from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:62:in
>   new
>           from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:62:in
>   driver
>           from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:48:in
>   start
>           from /opt/metasploit-framework/lib/metasploit/framework/command/base.rb:82:in
>   start
>           from /usr/local/bin/msfconsole:48:in

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete credit to Iraklis Mathiopoulos @https://medium.com/@iraklis/sometimes-you-need-metasploit-running-on-a-box-with-a-public-ip-in-order-to-get-reverse-shells-to-74fda07165a5#.2tplo6bnh:

#### Installing the Pre-requisites.

1. adduser msfdev
2. adduser msfdev sudo
3. apt-get update
4. apt-get -y install autoconf bison build-essential curl git-core libapr1 libaprutil1 libcurl4-openssl-dev libgmp3-dev libpcap-dev libpq-dev libreadline6-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libsvn1 libtool libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libyaml-dev locate ncurses-dev openssl wget xsel zlib1g zlib1g-dev

#### Using msfdev for install

1. su - msfdev
2. wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iam1980/metasploit-vps-installer/master/msf_vps_installer.sh
3. bash msf_vps_installer.sh

Answer (score -1):

I generally always use the free installer to install a standalone version of metasploit.

it is outlined here under installation.

You can simply git clone and then install

```
git clone https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework.git
```